# remove one Collection elements from other

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Hi i have two Collection of SomeType a1,a2 and want to remove all the elements of a2 from a1.

Please suggestion which type of Collection i need to use :

1. ArrayList
2. LinkList
3. some other ?.

Is there any library for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all. 
After reading your response i created a **Filter** class like this :

```
public class Filter {

    public <T> Set<T> filter(Set<T> all, Set<T> blocked) {
        for (T t : all) {
            if(blocked.contains(t)) {
                all.remove(t);
            }
        }
        return all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use the collection method `Collection.removeAll(Collection<?> c);`**

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use `a1.removeAll(a2)`, but the removal would be more efficient if your Collections are `HashSet` (since the search for an element in a HashSet takes `O(1)`, while in `List`s it takes `O(n)`). Whether you can use `HashSet` depends on whether a1 and a2 can contain duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2):

To remove from a collection you need to have objects(in your case SomeType) that override `equals` and `hashCode`.
Then you don't need a library, just use the `removeAll` method

```
Collection<SomeType> a1 = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
Collection<SomeType> a2 = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
a1.removeAll(a2);
```